# CSRF token required on the OAuth2 authorization endpoint

Tags: django, oauth

I am using `django-oauth-toolkit` to integrate the OAuth2 [Implicit Grant type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2) in my project.

When I try to access the authorization endpoint (typically, `http://localhost:8000/o/authorize/`), I am getting a 403 FORBIDDEN status and Django asks for the CSRF token.

Just to spare some comments on this post, it is good to know that I am working on a **cross-domain** application where the front-end is implemented in Javascript and I don't want to bother with CORS and cookies set across different domains (so no, the `csrftoken` cookie is **not available**), that is why I want to use OAuth and optionally some `state` information to act as a csrftoken-look-alike.

As an additional help for troubleshooting, I was able to get the request working on `http://localhost:8000/o/authorize/` from the same domain, using the `csrftoken` cookie as mentioned in the [official Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax). So it really looks like the authorization server is somehow protected by the Django CSRF thing. Is it what I should expect? I thought OAuth2 (and indirectly `django-oauth-toolkit`) would allow for a cross-domain client to authenticate without the need for a csrf token. What am I missing?

Finally I am not sure whether the order in which I have set up my middlewares could explain this behavior, but here is my current setting:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'oauth2_provider.middleware.OAuth2TokenMiddleware'
)
```

Should I put `OAuth2TokenMiddleware` before `CsrfViewMiddleware` or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

The authorization process starts with a GET of that url, presenting a form that has informations that are needed by the authorization process to create a GRANT token.

The default authorization form has a csrf_token as a field, this should be part of your POST data, if you don't want to have a csrf set in the request, you should subclass `oauth2_provider.views.base.AuthorizationView` and mark it as `csrf_exempt`, putting that url before the inclusion of the others of oauth toolkit.